# How to plot an histogram and a constant line from different files

Tags: plot, gnuplot, line, histogram

I'm new to **gnuplot** and I have a problem:

I have 2 different text files, the first one (`file1.txt`) is something like this:

```
Switch,Port,BPS
S1,1,5464091.33
S1,3,5465677.33
S2,2,5463298.00
S2,3,5462729.67
S3,1,5461340.67
S3,3,5461772.33
```

and I plot "file1.txt" with an histogram:

```
plot avg_file using 3:xticlabels(stringcolumn(1)."-".stringcolumn(2)) title columnheader
```

this works fine.

Now I have `file2.txt` which contains a single value:

```
AVG_BPS
4844714.81
```

I would like to plot this value as a constant horizontal line over the previous graph (histogram).

This is my complete script:

```
# Terminal definition (PNG image)
set term png

# Settings
set datafile separator ","
set output 'myplot.png'
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 1

# Graph and Axis titles
set title  "BPS"
set xlabel "Switch-Port"
set ylabel "bits-per-second"

# Plot
plot "file1.txt" using 3:xticlabels(stringcolumn(1)."-".stringcolumn(2)) title columnheader
```

Here is `myplot.png`: [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably the best is to do a `stats`:

```
stats 'file2.txt' u 1
hor_value=STATS_min
```

and then add to your plot:

```
plot "file1.txt" using 3:xticlabels(stringcolumn(1)."-".stringcolumn(2)) title columnheader, hor_value
```

or alternatively put a line on top (before the last plot):

```
set arrow nohead from graph 0, hor_value to graph 1, hor_value front
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with STATS. Just a little thing: when I run my script it prints some stats on the terminal, how can I prevent this?

Comment: stats has a `nooutput` flag. See `help stats` within gnuplot console.